# ASP.NET MVC routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using asp.net mvc 4 . I want to work with 3 - 4 route pattern , but I can't . it works just with one pattern :
this is my RouteConfig file :

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.Add(
        new Route("mycontroller/{action}/{mlid}/{countryid}/{cityid}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new
                { action="myaction",
                    mlid = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    countryid = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    cityid = UrlParameter.Optional,
                }),
                new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
        );
        routes.Add(
        new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new { controller = "start", action = "Index",id = UrlParameter.Optional}),
                new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
        );
```

I have a controller an action with 8 parameters . I want to use first pattern , but it use second pattern . I used Route Debugger but it does not help me . 
please help .

EDIT :

I use this code for navigation :

```
<a href="@Url.Action("myaction", "mycontroller", new { mlid = "1" })">test</a>
```

but it shows this in address bar :

```
http://localhost:12911/mycontroller/myaction?mlid=1
```

I want to show it this :

```
http://localhost:12911/mycontroller/myaction/1
```

EDIT :

This is my class :

```
public class HyphenatedRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
        {
            protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
            {
                if (requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] != null)
                {
                    requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["area"].ToString().Replace('-', '_');
                }
                requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
                requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
                return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you want your routes to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a routing debugger plugin to track it down. Then it's much easier to see what happens to the routes.

Scott Hanselman suggests Glimpse on this blog post of his:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek5DebuggingASPNETMVCApplicationsWithGlimpse.aspx

I tried to replicate your solution and created the following routes in my project:

```
        routes.Add(
            new Route("office/{action}/{mlid}/{countryid}/{cityid}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new
                {
                    controller = "office",
                    action = "index",
                    mlid = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    countryid = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    cityid = UrlParameter.Optional,
                }),
                new HyphenatedRouteHandler()
            )
        );
        routes.Add(
            new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
                    new HyphenatedRouteHandler()
                    )
        );
```

The route can also be added using MapRoute but then you have to write in the following way to be able to use the specific route handler.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "RegReq",
            url: "office/{action}/{mlid}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "office",
                action = "index",
                mlid = UrlParameter.Optional
            }).RouteHandler = new HyphenatedRouteHandler();
```

I then created an office controller with the optional mlid parameter as in this example:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? mlid)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I never created the view but added a break point here instead to see that mlid really got the id I was sending.

I then added the following link on the home controller's index view:

```
    <a href="@Url.Action("index", "office", new { mlid = "3" })">test</a>
```

And when I browse over the test link I get the following URL:

```
http://localhost:52788/office/index/3
```

Hopefully this can help you somewhere...

Comment: I used Route Debugger . but i didn't help me . everything is okay on Route Debugger but on browsing has issue .

Comment: Ok. I would try to add controller="mycontroller" to the RouteValueDictionary under the first route. There doesn't seem to be any controller set there so the routing engine might get confused by that.

Comment: Very strange! I created a test project in MVC4 (with my line added above) and then the links were created just in the way you wanted them. I'll update my suggestion (in a few seconds) with the code I was using...

Comment: In my controller example above I ignored all of the other optional parameters, as well as other code, but that was just to keep the example simple...

Comment: I used a normal route : `routes.MapRoute(
            name: "RegReq",
            url: "pro/index/{mainland}/{country}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "pro",
                action = "index",
                mainland = UrlParameter.Optional,
                country = UrlParameter.Optional
            });`

. now it works . but I need HyphenatedRouteHandler class !!

Comment: Ok, I think I've got an idea...add `..RouteHandler = new HyphenatedRouteHandler();` at the end of the MapRoute. I'll update my code example above with a full example...

Comment: So the thing that doesn't work is the links that become ?mlid=3 instead of /3 right? For me I got /3 for both of the route examples above...

Comment: Ok, now I've finally managed to create a solution where it shows `?mlid=3` and it was by intentionally write the wrong controller name in the link. By writing `<a href="@Url.Action("index", "office2", new { mlid = "3" })">test</a>` where **office** has been replaced with **office2** I managed to get the same problem as you did. All other times it did write `/3`. Can you please update your question with the actual routing code and actual link? Or is it the actual code you have there?

Answer (score 1):

First route does not specify controller at all. The Routing takes the second route and treats 'mlid' as overflow parameter, that is: route value not specified in route definition. Try this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("myaction", "mycontroller", new { id = 1 })">test</a>
```

It uses second route again, but this time parameter name matches to what is specified in the route. You can include as many parameters as you want, just add them to the route, i.e.

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}/{countryname}
```

With this, you'll have 'countryname' parameter in controller's RouteData and/or action parameter.

To use first route, assuming you want to use controller named 'mycontroller', try adding it as a default controller like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "routeName",
url: "mycontroller/{action}/{id}/{countryid}",
defaults: new { controller = "mycontroller",... }...
```

Comment: this works ! but when I want to do this : <a href="@Url.Action("myaction", "mycontroller", new { id = 1 , countryid = "2"})">test</a> , how it will be ?

Comment: it allways uses second route . i dont want this ! I want to use this link via first route .

Comment: you mean i use just one route ?

Comment: Yes, you used only second, default route, while generating link with Url.Action you got `http://localhost:12911/mycontroller/myaction?mlid=1`. It is link to controller 'mycontroller', with action 'myaction' and since the route does not specify mlid, but id parameter, you got it as a query string, instead of pretty `/1`

Comment: I have 8 parameters . It should be a like like :
`http://localhost:12911/mycontroller/myaction?mlid=1&p1=1&p2=1&p3=1...` . and in this way partials does not works ..

Comment: Yes I want to have a pretty url

Answer (score 0):

I think what Piotr was trying to say was that you need to modify this code to add a default controller so that this:

```
routes.Add(
    new Route("mycontroller/{action}/{mlid}/{countryid}/{cityid}",
        new RouteValueDictionary(
            new
            {
                action="myaction",
                mlid = UrlParameter.Optional,
                countryid = UrlParameter.Optional,
                cityid = UrlParameter.Optional,
            }),
            new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
    );
```

Becomes this:

```
routes.Add(
    new Route("mycontroller/{action}/{mlid}/{countryid}/{cityid}",
        new RouteValueDictionary(
            new
            {
                controller="mycontroller",
                action="myaction",
                mlid = UrlParameter.Optional,
                countryid = UrlParameter.Optional,
                cityid = UrlParameter.Optional,
            }),
            new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
    );
```

Though if you're going to require 10 parameters that are all optional, this may not be the best solution; It's gonna look damn ugly either way.